# How to disable back,home,multitask physical buttons?

Tags: android, button, android-homebutton

Actually i'm developing an app and just this app should be opened on the device where is installed so i would be able to block / disable physical buttons for back,home,multitask.

I've read yet some articles about how to do it but still can't get how to implement it in my app.

The buttons i would disable are the following that you can see on the photo
[image]

Comment: show us your code,where are you stuck?

Comment: Actually i was following this [guide](https://hackernoon.com/disable-android-home-back-and-active-apps-buttons-f7450dfeddcd) and i can't get how to implement onKeyDown method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Just put below code onStart() method

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // start lock task mode if it's not already active
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(
                Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // ActivityManager.getLockTaskModeState api is not available in pre-M.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!am.isInLockTaskMode()) {
                startLockTask();
            }
        } else {
            if (am.getLockTaskModeState() ==
                    ActivityManager.LOCK_TASK_MODE_NONE) {
                startLockTask();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: That's a great solution but it's give me a lot of annoying Toast's and also when i open the app is Saying "this screen is blocked etc..." can i disable all this stuff?

Comment: when startLockTask() called, system will ask user the permission for entering pinning mode.

Comment: yeah i've noticed it but i'm looking for something that doesn't permit to the user to decide if block it or not :l but anyway if i don't find anything other ill use this method

Comment: @akansha06jain While answering questions is great, it would benefit future users if you explain what your code did. Add some relevant information about the code.

Comment: Do you need a dedicated device? If yes you should give a look to this guide https://developer.android.com/work/cosu#java . Using a Device policy controller and whitelisting your package, if you call startLocktask() the "annoying" popup is not shown

Answer (score 3):

For `back button` you can `Override` `onBackPressed` method like below :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do what you want
}
```

For `Home Button`

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

For Disable `recent app` button : -

**Step 1**

Add this permission to the `manifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
```

**Step 2**

Put this code in any Activity on which you want to **block/disable the recent apps button**

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(getTaskId(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Canno't resolve method TYPE_KEYGUARD while with TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG the app crash with the following error: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.